# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters when using national characters

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to create some directories which have national symbols like "äöü" etc. Unfortunately I'm getting this exception whenever that is being attempted:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /home/pi/myFolder/löwen
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at org.someone.something.file.PathManager.createPathIfNecessary(PathManager.java:161)
...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My code where it occurs looks like this:

```
public static void createPathIfNecessary(String directoryPath) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(directoryPath);
        // if directory exists?
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        } else if (!Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            throw new IOException("The path " + path + " is not a directory as expected!");
        }
    }
```

I searched for possible solutions and most suggest to set the locale to UTF-8, so I thought I would get this fixed if I set the locale in Linux to UTF-8, but  I found out that it has already been UTF-8 all the time, and despite newly setting it, I'm still having the same problem.

```
 $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm not having this problem on Windows 7, it creates the directories perfectly, so I'm wondering whether I need to improve the java code to handle this situation better, or to change something in my Linux.

The Linux I'm running it on is a Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 2:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release

    PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
    NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
    VERSION_ID="7"
    VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
    ID=raspbian
    ID_LIKE=debian
    ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
    HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
    SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I am running my application on a Tomcat 7 Server (Java version is 1.8 I believe), my setenv.sh starts with: `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...`

Does anybody have a solution to this problem? I need to be able to use those national symbols in directory/file names...

**EDIT:**

After adding the extra option Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 at the start of my setenv.sh for Tomcat and restarting something changed.

Currently the my start of setenv.sh looks like this

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

it seems like this exception is gone and the folder with the national symbols gets created, however the problem seems to not be solved completely, whenever I try to create/write to files within that directory, I now get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/pi/myFolder/löwen/Lowen.tmp (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:156)
        at org.someone.something.MyFileWriter.downloadFiles(MyFileWriter.java:364)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The code where it happens looks like this:

```
// output here
File myOutputFile = new File(filePath);
FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(myOutputFile));
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
```

It seems to fail on (new FileOutputStream(myOutputFile)); when it's trying to initialize the FileOutputStream with the File object, which has the path created from a string which was retrieved from the path in the exception above and an added filename at the end.

So now the directory is created, however writing or creating anything inside it still results in the exception above, although the file inside it doesn't event contain national symbols.

Creating paths and files in them when they have no national symbols works as perfectly as it did before the change in setenv.sh, so it looks like the problem is connected to the national symbols within the path still...

Comment: The offender is clearly the o-umlaut character.  Does that directory already exist? If not, do you get an error when you do `mkdir /home/pi/myFolder/löwen`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, it is the ö character that is causing the problem. No, the path is not there yet, therefore the code next tries to create it if it's not there yet, but it fails when it's not created yet. If I do mkdir  command from bash via SSH it works perfectly, that's why I find this so weird. Can it be related to Java/Tomcat setup? But Tomcat seems to be somewhat setup to do file encoding with UTF-8, so I don't know what other possible points there are.

Comment: Is the path hardcoded somewhere in the source or is it user input or in a properties file?  Whatever the source of the path name, THAT is in a national character set and for some reason is not being converted to UTF-8, leading to the error.

Comment: Does the Unix filesystem actually support a filename like that? Can it be created from a shell?

Comment: @JimGarrison No, the path consists of some values, which are read from xml and a part (the one with the national symbol ö) read from email. Hmm, currently I added the extra option at the start of setenv.sh Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 while leaving the other one and it seems after restarting it doesn't throw this exception anymore, but it throws a new one and it must be related to the same problem, I edited my question

Comment: @LittleSanti Yes it can, i tried.

Answer (score 7):

just set environment variables "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" or some other "xxx.UTF-8".(https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html)

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_createDirectory(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
                                            jobject file)
{
    jboolean rv = JNI_FALSE;
 
    WITH_FIELD_PLATFORM_STRING(env, file, ids.path, path) {
        if (mkdir(path, 0777) == 0) {
            rv = JNI_TRUE;
        }
    } END_PLATFORM_STRING(env, path);
    return rv;
}
```

```
#define WITH_PLATFORM_STRING(env, strexp, var)                                
    if (1) {                                                                  
        const char *var;                                                      
        jstring _##var##str = (strexp);                                       
        if (_##var##str == NULL) {                                            
            JNU_ThrowNullPointerException((env), NULL);                       
            goto _##var##end;                                                
        }                                                                     
        var = JNU_GetStringPlatformChars((env), _##var##str, NULL);           
        if (var == NULL) goto _##var##end;
 
#define WITH_FIELD_PLATFORM_STRING(env, object, id, var)                      
    WITH_PLATFORM_STRING(env,                                                 
                         ((object == NULL)                                    
                          ? NULL                                              
                          : (*(env))->GetObjectField((env), (object), (id))), 
                         var)
```

1. Java natively translates all string to platform's local encoding in this method: jdk/src/share/native/common/jni_util.c - JNU_GetStringPlatformChars() . System property sun.jnu.encoding is used to determine the platform's encoding.
2. The value of sun.jnu.encoding is set at jdk/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c - GetJavaProperties() using setlocale() method of libc. Environment variable LC_ALL is used to set the value of sun.jnu.encoding. Value given at the command prompt using -Dsun.jnu.encoding option to Java is ignored.

(from https://stackoverrun.com/cn/q/3020937)

Comment: Try posting this as comment or elaborate your answer.

Comment: The reason is that Java versions prior to 18 take their encoding from the OS. Starting from [Java 18](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/18), UTF-8 is the default encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If the national characters are hardcoded in your source, convert the source file to the same encoding. You can use vim:

```
vim SourceClassWithHardcodedCharacters.java
:set fileencoding=utf-8<Enter>
:w<Enter>
```

If there is an issue, you will get a message ("unmappable character (...)").

For me, the issue is related either with 1. hardcoding characters in incorrect encoding or 2. losing the encoding somehow during passing the path to the method.

Answer (score 0):

In my Dockerfile basing on ubuntu, I had to add the following lines:

```
RUN apt-get install -y language-pack-de
RUN update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL de_DE.UTF-8
```

no other stuff worked, after that in my container the `LC_ALL` was set correct and the Java stuff works.

```
/$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```